# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/continue_label')

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Let me start off by saying I'm brand new to Android programming.  I'm using a Pragmatic's Hello Android book (3rd edition).  I'm working on the popular sudoku game example, and after copying the code from the book that is to be placed in the main.xml file, I get the following errors:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/background')
.
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/main_title').

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/continue_label').

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/new_game_label').

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/about_label').

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/exit_label').
```

They're probably all related, but after doing some searching, I don't know what the problem is.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your strings.xml, and colors.xml files from inside the Values folder in your res directory. Something in your resource folders is likely broken

Comment: have you put the values in the xml files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error says everything.You have a res folder where your resource like string/image/layout can reside.So you are referencing the resource but they are not present.Like you are referencing about_label string but in your string xml there is no tag for the string about_label and its value.See res->strings.Check all your xml file and put the resource you are trying to use in your program

Comment: Okay, I think I understand.  Upon looking into my book a little closer, I was missing some xml code in "strings.xml".  After that, I had to create a "colors.xml" file, add some code that the book calls for, and then import it into the project.  This was very helpful.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

For the string errors, you have to define your strings in the res/values/strings.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="main_title">My Main Title</string>
</resources>
```

The other errors are similar. The resources aren't defined in the res folder.

Answer (score 0):

Those resources are created in res/values/* folder (res/values/strings.xml or res/values/colors.xml etc...).
This allows you to use on string or color over and over again.

For now, you can replace these resources with actual String objects or literals, i.e. R.string.exit_label would be replaced with "Exit".